# Reliably read registry from installed web application

Tags: c#, permissions, wix, registry

I am using this code to *try* and read from the registry

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx

If I run the application from Visual Studio the code work as expected - it reads a key from the registry and check successfully if it is NullOrEmpty, if it is the user is redirected to the Activation page.

If I build my installer (WIX 3.7) and install it, the application appears to be ignoring the activation check.  It appears that it is failing to interact with the registry.

In the WIX installer I forcecreateoninstall and forceremoveonuninstall of the application key, leaving it blank initially.  I have added util:permissionEx to every key I can in the registrykey path, right down to the registryvalue...and yet  the check appears to be being ignored.

Works through Visual Studio, fail once installed.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
<Component Id="$(var.ProductName)RegistryKeys" Guid="A_GUID">
  <RegistryKey Id="FCSRegKey" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\CompanyName" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
    <util:PermissionEx User="$(var.ProductName)AppPool" Domain="IIS APPPOOL" Read="yes" Write="yes"
GenericRead="yes"
GenericWrite="yes"
GenericExecute="yes"
Delete="yes"
TakeOwnership="yes"/>
  <RegistryKey Key="$(var.ProductName)$(var.Version)$(var.Edition)" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
    <util:PermissionEx  User="$(var.ProductName)AppPool"
      Domain="IIS APPPOOL"
      Read="yes"
      Write="yes" GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes"                                     GenericExecute="yes"
Delete="yes"
TakeOwnership="yes"/>
  <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="$(var.KeyName)" Value="" KeyPath="yes">
    <util:PermissionEx  User="$(var.ProductName)AppPool"
      Domain="IIS APPPOOL"
      Read="yes"
      Write="yes"
      GenericRead="yes"
      GenericWrite="yes"
      GenericExecute="yes"
      Delete="yes"
      TakeOwnership="yes"/>
  </RegistryValue>
</RegistryKey>
</RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

What on earth am I doing wrong?

I am using Windows 7 SP 1 on a 64-bit machine

Cheers and Thanks,

Incredibly frustrated.

Comment: Your question seems to be about reading the registry, but then you spend most of the time talking about Wix installers.  What exactly do you think is not working?  Does the key get written?  How does the code fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much information here, so this is just an informed guess.  Your installer is writing to the 32-bit registry, which is where your program will read from when you run it under VS.  When it actually runs under IIS, it's a 64-bit process, so it reads from an entirely different part of the registry.